# Establecer un email remitente usando una clase Mailable en Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

A la hora de mandar un email desde un formulario de contacto, el email remitente se establece como el mío propio, es decir, como si me auto mandara un correo electrónico. Poseo el siguiente formulario:

```
       <form action="{{ route("email.send") }}" method="post">

                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com">
                        <small class="text-muted">No es necesario que se registre</small>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="3" cols="1" class="md-textarea form-control"
                                  style="resize: none">
                        </textarea>

                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Enviar</button>

                </form>
```

Donde recojo el email remitente y el mensaje que se desea mandar al administrador de la página web. La información recogida la mando al controlador MailController, donde se encuentra la función encargada de "tramitar" el email:

```
public function send()
{

    Mail::to("mail@gmail.com")
        ->send(new Suggestions(request("message")));

    if (Mail::failures()) {
        return redirect(route("homepage"))->with("error", "Error al enviar el e-mail");
    } else {
        return redirect(route("homepage"))->with("success", "Tu sugerencia se tendrá en cuenta ¡Atent@ a los cambios!");
    }

}
```

También poseo la clase Mailable, llamada Suggestions, donde se encuentra el método build, encargado de construir como tal el mensaje:

```
 public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("Sugerencias")
            ->from("hello@gmail.com")
            ->markdown("emails.suggestionMail");
    }
```

Y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: email recibido]

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Considera no publicar datos sensibles como el caso de tu cuenta de correo

Comment: @Aprendiz Es un correo de ejemplo. No lo usaré para compartir información como tal. Aún así, gracias por la advertencia